# Angular: How to maintain unformatted text from content editable div

Tags: angular, typescript

Apologies if the title lacks detail. I don't know how to word it really.

**What I am trying to do:**
I have a div with content editable and I am using angular-mentions npm to mention a another user. When a user writes a comment and selects another user from the list, it inserts it as ##userId## which I then use to search for a user in a list and replace that part of the text with

```
<span style="font-weight: bold; color: #0072f0">@' + user[0].fullName + '</span>
```

To give it a color and make it appear as @userName.

**My problem:**
The text I display should contain the formatted text with the style and not show ##userId##. But the text I save should be the unformatted text with the ##userId##.

Text displayed in the div while typing: Good day @Richard

Text I save after a comment is posted: Good day ##RichardsUserId##

I tried to use (input) on the div to update the comment on each keystroke but of course this will overwrite the string with the span element instead of maintaining the hashtags. So my question is how can I maintain a different versions of a string while typing, the one displayed and the one saved. I can't just replace the span element with the ##userId## at the end because I will have no connection to which user it is as users can have the same name so I have to maintain the ID.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkihdq

**HTML:**

```
<div id="commentInput"
    class='commentInput'
    placeholder="Add Comment..."       
    [mention]="users"
    [mentionConfig]="mentionConfig"
    contenteditable="true"
    (itemSelected)="itemSelected($event)">
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
 comment: string;

  mentionConfig = {
    labelKey:'fullName', 
    dropUp: true,
    allowSpace: true,
    mentionSelect: (e: any) => {
      return '##' + e.userId + '##';
    }
  };

  public htmlCode: string;
  public htmlDoc: HTMLElement;
  @Input() users: Users;

    itemSelected(event: any) {

    let user: string = this.users.filter(user => user.userId === event.userId)[0].fullName;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.htmlDoc = document.getElementById('commentInput');
      this.htmlDoc.innerHTML = this.htmlDoc.innerHTML.replace(
        '##' + event.userId + '##',
        ' <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #0072f0">@' + user + '</span>&nbsp;'
      );
      // put the cursor to the end of field again...
      this.selectEnd();
    }, 10);
  }

  selectEnd() {
    let range, selection;
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this.htmlDoc);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
```

So any idea how I can bind the content editable text to comment but of course keep the ##userId## and not the html?

Comment: Could you put all this code in stackblitz.com and make it work? To see it running so we can edit it and give you a better answer.

Comment: Here you go https://angular-ivy-kkihdq.stackblitz.io

As you will see, after adding a mention the unformatted text does correctly add the ##userId## but if you continue typing after it gets overridden with the name. I want to prevent that

Comment: Wrong link, right one here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkihdq

Answer (score 0):

If you just separate your saved html code from the displayed one by using two variables. For instance htmlDisplay and htmlToSave. Then you could just update your htmlToSave each time you you update our htmlDisplay.